# Fetching items from table A, which is linked to table C via table B. Triple join?

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

Suppose a site categorizes popular stories according to the media format in which they are released. Its database consists of the following tables:

[image: stories table]

[image: links table]

[image]

**What kind of query or queries should be used to retrieve all story titles released in the form of, say, a movie?**

I thought of doing something like this, but suspect that there's a better method:

```
SELECT `story_id`
FROM `links` INNER JOIN `media`
  ON `links`.`medium_id` = `media`.`medium_id`
  WHERE `media`.`medium_name` = :medium_name"

for every retrieved story_id
{
    SELECT `story_summary` FROM `stories` WHERE `story_id` = :story_id
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s.story_title
from stories s, links l, media m
where m.medium_name = 'movie' and
s.story_id = l.story_id and
l.medium_id = m.medium_id
```

This is essentially the same query as raheel posted, just different syntax.
Is there a reason the stories and medium tables are not joined directly? Your queries and db could be simplified.

Comment: Oh, that could be - I'm no expert, not by far. Figured this would be the best way to set up the tables if every story can have multiple media forms.

This syntax seems much simpler to me but I haven't gotten it to work in my project so far... still trying.

Comment: Haven't got it working in my PHP script yet, but if I run the query directly in PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly. Is there any downside to this method as opposed to the (more complicated?) JOIN? I've never really used JOINs before, I must admit, have always done things 'manually'in multiple queries.

Comment: My query is an older syntax and the type of join is implied. The query @raheel_shan posted is a newer syntax that explicitly defines the join type. If you are going to learn one I'd go with the newer syntax.

Comment: Haven't done php for a while but the php query may prefer that movie in line 3 is in double quotes: "movie"?

Comment: @ScottyBoy you should know this is a cartisian product and must be avoided, joins are faster and this old syntex is slower. Also cartisian will fetch undersired results unless you restrict them with where.

Answer (score 1):

try with this query instead ( I added the third line and the last one):

```
SELECT `story_id` FROM `links` 
INNER JOIN `media` ON `links`.`medium_id` = `media`.`medium_id`
inner join stories on stories.story_ID=links.story_id
 WHERE `media`.`medium_name` = :medium_name
and `story_summary`.`story_id` in (:all_the_story_id)
```

:**all_the_story_id** there put all the story_id, take a look to [mysql in](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

If you make an Extra Join you will have all the info that you need, and you wont need to make a query for each result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    s.story_title
FROM MEDIA as m
LEFT JOIN LINKS as l ON l.medium_id = m.medium_id
LEFT JOIN STORIES as s ON s.story_id = l.story_id
WHERE m.medium_name = 'movie'
```

Comment: Going with this as per your and Scotty Boy's recommendation. Could you please explain to me why a LEFT JOIN is required? This variation which I find to be more readable seems to work very well using an INNER JOIN: http://codepad.org/rBlxBIyU

Comment: there is a little difference between LEFT and INNER. Inner fetches the record which exist in both the tables means in the left and right joined tables while left join always fetches the left table results and about right table it fetches the null result if record does not exist. But using inner, records must exist in both tables